# Find the first day of the month a given date is in

Tags: perl

In Perl, given a variable $period_end_date being set to, say, '4/30/2014', how can you set $period_start_date to '4/1/2014' and $next_period_start_date to '5/1/2014'?  (i.e. set to the first of the month and the first of the next month respectively.

I've tried using the DateTime module but my system could not find it. I was thinking to use substr to extract the pieces but the month and day can have 1 or 2 digits.

How would I change what's in between the /'s with a 1?

Comment: There's gotta be a gazillion questions asking this. What have you tried?

Comment: *I've tried using the DateTime module but my system could not find it.* If you don't have DateTime installed, then install it. You can do that via the cpan tool on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the input data will always be in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, and you're really only worried about the fact that `mm` and `dd` can have either one or two digits, then you can use regex matching:

```
$period_end_date =~ m{(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)};
my $month = $1;
my $day   = $2;
my $year  = $3;
```

I used the `m{}` format for pattern matching rather than `//` in order to avoid having to escape the `/` characters within the date.  You could write 
the pattern `/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/` instead.

Comment: Better: `my ($month, $day, $year) = $period_end_date =~ m{(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)};` Avoids globals. Avoids using putting bad data in `$month`, `$day` and `$year` when there wasn't a match.

Comment: Yes, that is a better style.

Comment: In my opinion, `my ($month, $day, $year) = $period_end_date =~ /\d+/g` is clearer still, since there is presumably no need to validate the date string. But the OP has other ideas

Comment: I added some basic validation on the month and day after getting them.  I suppose this is not as good as validating the original string.

Comment: The best style depends partly on how well you (or whoever inherits the code from you) can remember the idioms.  I've written some very concise code in the past and then kicked myself (metaphorically) a few months later when I had to update the code and got confused by my own cleverness.  But it is good to know about `/pattern/g`, because for more complex patterns or for scanning multiple strings in one block of code it could be _very_ much better than the non-`g` alternative.

Comment: @michaelc35: Where does your original date string come from? Unless it is typed in by hand (when you should validate it as soon as you receive the input line) there is no point in validating it at all. If you can't rely on the validity of the output of another program then you can't begin to process it further.

Comment: The original date is typed in by hand on the command line.  How would I validate it at that point before trying to get the individual parts?  I validated it after trying to get the parts for simplicity.  I know the user could enter some wacky string.  I tried a couple wacky strings and it either outputs a long perl error or it catches it when it tries validating the day and month.

Comment: When trying ededed04/30/14, I got Syntax error during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value 'ededed04/30/14' to a DATE field.  With wwwwwwww, I get Invalid Date: Format is mm/dd/yy e.g. 4/30/14 per my day/month validation.

Comment: @michaelc35: I would have thought it was best to make sure that only valid dates are stored in the database. It is too late to warn the operator when you read it back from storage. You need to make sure that the string is a possible date (i.e. not something like 2/30/2014) as well as just checking that it is `dd/dd/dddd` or similar. But this discussion doesn't really belong here

Comment: Well yeah getting into leap year verifications would be needed for a true validation.  Point noted.  FYI I added a check on the year to catch dddd years. Thanks for the help.  It is starting to come together.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

Rather than using a more complex regex, this solution just pulls out all the numeric fields from the string.

The calculation simply increments the month, and also increments the year if the month has wrapped around to 1.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $period_end_date = '4/30/2014';

my @mdy = $period_end_date =~ /\d+/g;

$mdy[1] = 1;
my $period_start_date = sprintf '%02d/%02d/%04d', @mdy;

$mdy[0] = $mdy[0] % 12 + 1;
++$mdy[2] if $mdy[0] == 1;
my $next_period_start_date = sprintf '%02d/%02d/%04d', @mdy;

print "$_\n" for $period_end_date, $period_start_date, $next_period_start_date;
```

**output**

```
4/30/2014
04/01/2014
05/01/2014
```

Comment: I like the more complex regex solution to get the numbers but thanks for mentioning the modulus operator for the resulting math.